# Convert coordinates to a ROS Message

Tags: ros, coordinates, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have the task to write a program (C++) to convert the coordinates (x, y, z) into a ROS Message.
I have read the coordinates and stored them in array.
Now i have convert these coordinates into a ROS Message.

I have no idea how to carry on

Can someone help me like I have to?

Hello,

I have the task to write a program (C++) to convert the coordinates (x, y, z) into a ROS Message.
I have read the coordinates and stored them in array.
Now i have convert these coordinates into a ROS Message.

Can someone help me like I have to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277922/convert-coordinates-to-a-ros-message/) by [Chris_ROSuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/32963/chris_rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29 shows you how to publish a string message using C++. You will need to choose an appropriate message type to publish the values you want instead of String, import that message definition instead and set the fields then publish it

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1